# Is it good to have the total amount and the discount in the order table

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have two tables `Orders` and `OrderItem`.

```
Order
-------------------
order_id
order_number
order_date
total_amount
total_discount //discount sum up of individual item's percentage discount
coupon_discount //discount from coupon
net_amount
```

and:

```
OrderItem
--------------------
order_item_id
order_id
item_id
quantity
price
discount_per
```

I am confused as to what data should I store in these two tables.
I think that the item price and the discount should be there because they might change frequently. But what about the others?
I am also confused as to whether I should store the discount percentage or just the calculated discount or both?

Comment: In general the discount applied to separate item and discount applied to the while order may exist. So the first type discount info must be stored in `OrderItem`, and the second one in `Order`. Total discount sum not needed to be stored because it can be calculated from existing separate discount sums.

Comment: But if I need to calculate net amount, I need total discount. If I have to loop through each item for discount. Then it's wise not to store total amount as well, and also the net amount. I should just store coupon discount there. What do you say @Akina ?

Comment: No problems, store if you want. But you must understand that it is possible that (by some custom reason - from some error till legitimate or deliberate edition) the total discount stored and total discount calculated may differ...

Comment: That's why I don't want to store total amount instead calculate each time. :)

Comment: I don't understand your needs. I know "can be calculated == must be non-stored, cannot be calculated == must be stored". Of course the calculation must be deterministic, the same value must be obtained today, tomorrow, a year later...

Comment: For starters, it's a **very bad** idea to use an SQL keyword as a table name - it's can easily lead to errors, and confusion on debugging! Call it `order_` or use a local word or even `orders` (normally, I use the singular for table names). Secondly, it is **imperative** that you give your MySQL version - they've made a lot of changes recently in versions 5.7/8 which will have a large impact on any answer that we might be able to give. Finally, (and I don't wish to appear to be giving out! :-) ), in future, please provide your table structures as DML (`SHOW CREATE TABLE foo\G`).

Comment: it's `orders` here it's typo, and normally I use plural names for tables and singular for models, thanks!